# Copy row in SQLite on iPad application

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am looking to copy a single row from one identical table to another in SQLite. Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO savedarticles (headline, author, authorid, lead, contents, section, added, updated, dturl, storyid, pubDate, slot)
SELECT (headline, author, authorid, lead, contents, section, added, updated, dturl, storyid, pubDate, slot)
FROM articles
WHERE articles.storyid = '14556068'
```

And here is the error message SQLite is giving me.

```
DB Error: 1 "near ",": syntax error"
```

Am I going about copying a row all wrong? I would prefer to do the copy 100% with sql instead of creating an object and doing an insert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need parentheses on the SELECT:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT headline, author, authorid, lead, contents, section, added, updated, dturl, storyid, pubDate, slot
FROM ...
```

And you don't need to quote the 14556068 unless it really is a string:

```
WHERE articles.storyid = 14556068
```

Everything is a string in SQLite so it won't care but good habits are good habits.